# Copying found blocks to another block in pure js

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is an algorithm for finding blocks "p" in which there is a search string, how to make the found blocks "p" copied into the block "block" with the same highlighting of the line that is now with pure js?

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p')

input.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const searchTerm = e.target.value
  const regex = new RegExp(searchTerm, 'g')
  const replacement = `<span class="highlighted">${ searchTerm }</span>`

  for (const p of paragraphs) {
    p.innerHTML = p.innerText.replace(regex, replacement)
  }
})
```

```css
.search__container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.search__input {
  border: 2px solid var(--dark-color);
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.search__input:hover,
.search__input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: var(--primary-color);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0.1px var(--primary-color);
          box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0.1px var(--primary-color);
}

.highlighted {
  text-shadow: 0 0 6px var(--primary-color);
  color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

```html
 
    <section class="search__container">
      <input class="search__input" type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="search..." />
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="paragraphs">
        <p>Killing it</p> I have zero cycles<p> for this, yet rock Star/Ninja, </p>and today shall be a cloudy day, <p> thanks to blue sky thinking,</p> we can now deploy our new ui to the </div>
      </div>
    </section><div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method:

```
      block.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", p.cloneNode(true))
```

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p')
const block = document.querySelector(".block");

input.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const searchTerm = e.target.value
  const regex = new RegExp(searchTerm, 'g')
  const replacement = `<span class="highlighted">${ searchTerm }</span>`
  block.innerHTML = "";
  for (const p of paragraphs) {
    if (p.innerText.match(regex) && searchTerm) {
      p.innerHTML = p.innerText.replace(regex, replacement);    
      block.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", p.cloneNode(true));
    }
  }
})
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: red;
  --dark-color: gray;
}

.search__container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.search__input {
  border: 2px solid var(--dark-color);
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.search__input:hover,
.search__input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: var(--primary-color);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0.1px var(--primary-color);
          box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0.1px var(--primary-color);
}

.highlighted {
  text-shadow: 0 0 6px var(--primary-color);
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.block {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 2px solid violet;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section class="search__container">
      <input class="search__input" type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="search..." />
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="paragraphs">
        <p>Killing it</p> I have zero cycles<p> for this, yet rock Star/Ninja, </p>and today shall be a cloudy day, <p> thanks to blue sky thinking,</p> we can now deploy our new ui to the </div>
      </div>
    </section><div class="block"></div>
  </main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `keyup` event for this and cleanup `span` tags before every new DOM update.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');

input.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  let searchTerm = e.target.value;
  let regex = new RegExp(searchTerm, 'g');
  let clean1 = new RegExp('</span>', 'g');
  let clean2 = new RegExp('<span class="highlighted">', 'g');
  let replacement = `<span class="highlighted">${ searchTerm }</span>`;
  
  for (let p of paragraphs) {
    replace(p,clean1, '');
    replace(p,clean2, '');
    replace(p,regex, replacement);
  }
})

function replace(p,reg,rep){
   p.innerHTML = p.innerText.replace(reg, rep);
}
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section class="search__container">
  <input class="search__input" type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="search..." />
</section>
<section>
  <div class="paragraphs">
    <p>Killing it</p> 
    <p>I have zero cycles</p>
    <p> for this, yet rock Star/Ninja, </p>
    <p>and today shall be a cloudy day,
    <p> thanks to blue sky thinking,</p>
    <p>we can now deploy our new ui to the </p>
  </div>
</section><div class="block"></div>
```